# Increase the display name length for user profile property

Tags: powershell, user-profile-service, user-profile-property

I want to add a custom user profile property whose display name is more that 50 characters. I am unable to do so using UI or PowerShell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The maximum length of the User Profile Core Property Name and Display Name is 50 characters. It's enforced in the setter. Why do you need more than 50 characters?

Comment: Oh! Client requirement :(

Comment: Change the requirement.